# if and &&,which writing is the best

Tags: php

```
if (empty($_GET['param'])) {
    $_GET['param'] = 1;
}
```

and

```
empty($_GET['param']) && $_GET['param'] = 1;
```

These two codings do the same work, but I wonder which coding is the best, is there any difference between them?

Comment: *codings do the same work* no way the fist one sets if empty the secound one tests if empty and pseudo-test sets ... don't use the secound one

Comment: second one is bad practice, don't use it.

Comment: You can see the differences if you look at the [VLD output for each](https://3v4l.org/jsSC7/vld#tabs)

Comment: @donald123 I think they work the same. $_GET['param'] will be set to 1 if it's empty. As the Yii2 and CodeIgniter use the second one.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thx alot! Now I know the second one will have 2 more ops

Comment: @aszx0413 the result is the same but working semantic not!